# Converting Text to AP (Associated Press) Style

Tags: python, text, string-formatting, cpu-word, python-pptx

I am working on a PPTX formatting project for which I have to convert the text into Associated Press Style. Do we have any library in python which could help me?

I have explored options available in pyapa, this only gives me the matching rate and it did not help me to convert the existing text. Can anyone help please?

Example of what I am trying to achieve:

input: hello! welcome to the us. we are happy to welcome you to our country.
output in AP style: Hello! Welcome to the US. We Are Happy to Welcome You to Our Country.

I have some content saved in 'page_content'... below is the code that I used:

```
from pyapa import pyapa 
a = pyapa.ApaCheck() 
a.match(page_content) 
a.Matches[1].print()
```

This is the output:

> Match from 575 to 613 for:
>
> Target: theremotesensingdata.Traditionalclassi Feedback: Every period
>   should be followed by a space. Suggestion: theremotesensingdata.

Traditionalclassi The output is just giving me the results, what I want is to convert the text in '`Page_content`' to AP style.

Comment: Any code please ?

Comment: I have some content saved in 'page_content'... below is the code that I used:

from pyapa import pyapa
a = pyapa.ApaCheck()
a.match(page_content)
a.Matches[1].print()

This is the output:

Match from 575 to 613 for:
Target: theremotesensingdata.Traditionalclassi
Feedback: Every period should be followed by a space.
Suggestion: theremotesensingdata. Traditionalclassi

The output is just giving me the results, what I want is to convert the text in 'Page_content' to AP style.